# How to obtain the current location data as a sharable link (Android App Development)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sms

I am working on an app that obtains the current location of the device as a link, and sends it as SMS to a specified number. The link which when clicked, must open google maps with the current location of the device marked on it.

I checked developer docs and could find ***fused location provider***.

But that doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Comment: "But that doesn't seem to be relevant here" -- why not? Use it to find the location. Use that latitude and longitude to create a Maps URL that will show that location. Use that URL in your SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fused location provider, I used the LocationManager() and LocationListener().

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    textView.append("\nLatitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            };
           locationManager.requestSingleUpdate("gps", locationListener, null);
```